# New AD User Issues

Tags: active-directory, permissions, samba

I apologise for the vague title of this question, but I'm not sure the appropriate wording.
Here's my issues with the new user/computer;

- Can't Remote Desktop to any Domain users on new PC (Though I can RDP to local admin account)
  **[Solved] by logging in with local Admin user and adding DOMAIN\UserGroup to the allowed RDP users, see yagmoth555's answer below.**
- Not seeing the new user on our Linux Samba server with `getent passwd control5` or `net usersidlist`

I added the new control5 user in AD, then I joined the new Windows PC to the domain, and thus the computer was created in AD.

I've also applied the same permissions for the new user as our existing (i.e. member of the same groups and security tab settings matching). I can't see any other differences between this new user and our existing users.

I'm not sure if it's an issue with the computer and/or user permissions.
Happy to provide any information requested, just let me know what would be helpful.

Extra: 
On the Linux Samba server I can see our other domain users, and they are working when mounting from their respective Windows PC - I assume this means the Linux server is talking to AD correctly? Though when I run `adinfo -m` it reports `disconnected` though I can run `net rpc join ...` and successfully join the domain.

**Can you please point me in the right direction, perhaps with some tests, to figure out where my issue may be?**
*Very hard to Google when I'm not sure the nature of the issue.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ok I solved my issues, here's how I did it.**

*I had two separate issues, I wasn't sure if the cause was related to both which is why my question may be a bit hard to understand.*

1. The first issue was sort of resolved using yagmoth555's suggestion. Adding the Domain User to the Remote Desktop Selected Users did make RDP work - however we were still missing some Admin functionality when logged in as the new Domain User, unable view the device manager for example.

   I had to login to the new Windows PC as the local administrator, and add the Domain User to the local administrator group. I find this a bit backwards as I envisaged Active Directory to handle all permission settings - this could very well be just how our DC is configured, though I didn't do the initial config.

---

2. The second issue was that our CentrifyDC connection had gone stale on our Linux Samba server. I was seeing the disconnection status with `adinfo -m` but had no idea how to 'connect' it, especially as `net rpc join ...` was working. After going down the route of Googling CentrifyDC issues, I found this lovely command on a forum;

   `sudo adkeytab -r -u [ad-admin-user] -V`
   *Apparently this will reset the local keytab after it's been inactive for some time (not really sure what any of that means to be honest).*

   Lo and behold after reseting that keytab I was seeing the new user with `getent passwd control5` and everything else began to work as expected, i.e. mounting the samba shares with that new users.

Hope this can be of use for someone.

Answer (score 2):

**For your question #1**

Make sure you have listed user in that Windows (Under **Select Users...**); as local administrator account bypass that strategy.

[image]

**For your question #2**

I'am not sure I understand the problem correctly, but make sure you can navigate to your samba server from the computer in problem, \linux_server_ip, and please report if you see an username/password error, or any errors you can see while it connect. Stated as is, I'am not sure you have a connection problem, or just a missing share for the user.

***nb, Next time please make sure to have only one question by question, it's easier to get an answer from the community.***

Comment: For remote desktop, when I log into the new PC with the new domain user, all the RDP settings are greyed out. For Samba mounting, on the new PC if I try to connect with the new user I get `The specified network password is not correct` then if I use an existing domain user I get `An extended error has occurred`. Sorry for the question confusion, I think the solution will hopefully relate to both issues which is why I put it all in one question.

Comment: More to this, the users were set to only login from their respective machine. After allowing them to login from anywhere, I was able to mount the Samba share on the new PC using existing domain users, but still not the new user I created.

Comment: @HuckleberryFinn Please check that windows I gave, to see who is listed, to know who can RDP-in.

Comment: Ah thank you, yes logging in with the local admin account I was able to add DOMAIN\User Group and now that's working with the Domain users. Do you have any thoughts on the other issue?

Comment: @HuckleberryFinn It state password not correct, can you log locally in ssh with that account to test the password ?

Comment: I can't SSH even with the existing domain users, I believe they don't have SSH permission. Though when I run `wbinfo -u` I can see all the users as expected, but when I run `getent passwd control5` I get no output. Running `getent password control2` shows output, so it's almost like the Linux server isn't fully informed about this new user - not sure if it requires I do something explicit to create it other than on the AD server.